# API Laravel - Call Store Procedure with IN and OUT parameter using OCI8 or PDO

Tags: laravel, stored-procedures, pdo, laravel-8, oci8

I'm new in Laravel 8. 
Connection from Laravel to Oracle SQL Developer: yajra/oci8 
I want to call my store procedure in oracle database using API Laravel.
my store procedure have 3 IN parameters and 4 OUT parameters.

I have few solution but it didn't work. (Tested in postman)

Here's my code in API :
(my solution 1 and 2, based on : https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-oci8/master/stored-procedure)

my solution 1 :

```
public function checkLogin01(Request $request) {
    $procedureName = 'myschema.VERIFY_LOGIN';

    $pIsSuccess = "";
    $pMsg = "";
    $pLastScope = "";
    $pParam = "";

    $bindings = [
        'pUserLogin' => $request['userLogin'],
        'pUserPassword' => $request['passLogin'],
        'pIPLogin' => $request['userLogin'],
        'pIsSuccess' => $pIsSuccess,
        'pMsg' => $pMsg,
        'pLastScope' => $pLastScope,
        'pParam' => $pParam,
    ];

    $result = DB::executeProcedure($procedureName, $bindings);

    return response()->json([
        'bindings' => $bindings, 
        'IsSuccess' => $pIsSuccess, 
        'Msg' => $pMsg, 
        'LastScope' => $pLastScope, 
        'Param' => $pParam, 
    ], 422);
}
```

error message from solution 1 :

> "message": "Error Code    : 6502\nError Message : ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small\nORA-06512: at "myschema.VERIFY_LOGIN", line 88\nORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small\nORA-06512: at line 1\nPosition      : 0\nStatement     : begin myschema.VERIFY_LOGIN(:pUserLogin,:pUserPassword,:pIPLogin,:pIsSuccess,:pMsg,:pLastScope,:pParam); end;\nBindings      : [hadi,pass1234,hadi,,,,]\n",
> "exception": "Yajra\Pdo\Oci8\Exceptions\Oci8Exception",

my Solution 2 :

```
public function checkLogin02(Request $request) {
    $pdo = DB::getPdo();

    $pIsSuccess = "";
    $pMsg = "";
    $pLastScope = "";
    $pParam = "";

    $procedureName = 'myschema.VERIFY_LOGIN';
    
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("begin " . $procedureName . " (:pUserLogin, :pUserPassword, :pIPLogin, :pIsSuccess, :pMsg, :pLastScope, :pParam); end;");
    $stmt->bindParam(':pUserLogin', $request['userLogin'], PDO::PARAM_STR); // this is line 208 from error message
    $stmt->bindParam(':pUserPassword', $request['passLogin'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':pIPLogin', $request['userLogin'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':pIsSuccess', $pIsSuccess, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 4000);
    $stmt->bindParam(':pMsg', $pMsg, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 4000);
    $stmt->bindParam(':pLastScope', $pLastScope, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 4000);
    $stmt->bindParam(':pParam', $pParam, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 4000);
    
    $stmt->execute();

    return response()->json([
        'bindings' => $bindings, 
        'IsSuccess' => $pIsSuccess, 
        'Msg' => $pMsg, 
        'LastScope' => $pLastScope, 
        'Param' => $pParam, 
    ], 422);
}
```

error message from solution 2 :

> "message": "Indirect modification of overloaded element of Illuminate\Http\Request has no effect",
> "exception": "ErrorException",
> "file": "/opt/lampp/htdocs/Hadi/projectname/app/Http/Controllers/AuthController.php",
> "line": 208,

my solution 3:

```
public function checkLogin03(Request $request) {
    $pdo = DB::getPdo();

    $pIsSuccess = "";
    $pMsg = "";
    $pLastScope = "";
    $pParam = "";

    $procedureName = 'myschema.VERIFY_LOGIN';
    
    DB::statement("call " . $procedureName . "(:pUserLogin, :pUserPassword, :pIPLogin, :pIsSuccess, :pMsg, :pLastScope, :pParam)" , [
        ':pUserLogin' => $request['userLogin'],
        ':pUserPassword' => $request['passLogin'],
        ':pIPLogin' => $request['userLogin'],
        ':pIsSuccess' => $pIsSuccess,
        ':pMsg' => $pMsg,
        ':pLastScope' => $pLastScope,
        ':pParam' => $pParam
    ]);

    return response()->json([
        'bindings' => $bindings, 
        'IsSuccess' => $pIsSuccess, 
        'Msg' => $pMsg, 
        'LastScope' => $pLastScope, 
        'Param' => $pParam, 
    ], 422);
}
```

error message from solution 3:

> "message": "Error Code    : 6502\nError Message : ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small\nORA-06512: at "myschema.VERIFY_LOGIN", line 89\nORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small\nPosition      : 5\nStatement     : call myschema.VERIFY_LOGIN(:pUserLogin, :pUserPassword, :pIPLogin, :pIsSuccess, :pMsg, :pLastScope, :pParam)\nBindings      : [hadi,pass1234*,hadi,,,,]\n (SQL: call myschema.VERIFY_LOGIN(:pUserLogin, :pUserPassword, :pIPLogin, :pIsSuccess, :pMsg, :pLastScope, :pParam))",
> "exception": "Illuminate\Database\QueryException",
> "file": "/opt/lampp/htdocs/Hadi/projectname/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php",
> "line": 712,

please help me how to fix it. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had ditch Eloquent and resort to vanilla PDO solution which works without errors.

```
public function cekLogin(Request $request) {
    $pdo = DB::getPdo();

    $pIsSuccess = "";
    $pMsg = "";
    $pLastScope = "";
    $pParam = "";

    $procedureName = 'myschema.VERIFY_LOGIN';
    
    $userLogin = $request['userLogin'];
    $passLogin = $request['passLogin'];
    $userLogin = $request['userLogin'];
    
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("begin " . $procedureName . " (:pUserLogin, :pUserPassword, :pIPLogin, :pIsSuccess, :pMsg, :pLastScope, :pParam); end;");
    $stmt->bindParam(':pUserLogin', $userLogin, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':pUserPassword', $passLogin, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':pIPLogin', $userLogin, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':pIsSuccess', $pIsSuccess, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 4000);
    $stmt->bindParam(':pMsg', $pMsg, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 4000);
    $stmt->bindParam(':pLastScope', $pLastScope, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 4000);
    $stmt->bindParam(':pParam', $pParam, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 4000);
    
    $stmt->execute();

    return response()->json([
        'IsSuccess' => $pIsSuccess, 
        'Msg' => $pMsg, 
        'LastScope' => $pLastScope, 
        'Param' => $pParam, 
    ], 422);
}
```